# I have a Drupal site which uses Organic Groups but my 'Create Group' button only shows for admin?

Tags: drupal, menu, permissions, organic-groups

I've created a Drupal site and used the organic groups module, set up a content type 'Group' and made a menu link that links to node/add/group and placed this in the main menu. But I can only see this when I log in as the admin user. I want all authenticated members to be able to create groups. Any ideas where Ive gone wrong? I worked through some tutorials for setting up Organic Groups - is this a permission setting? does drupal think that authenticated users don't have permission to create groups?

thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a permission setting if you haven't yet assigned the permission to create groups to authenticated users on /admin/people/permissions/list.